# Is it possible to parse these dates

Tags: java, date

Is it possible to parse dates like these in Java :

`Sunday February 09th, 2014 or Sunday February 21st, 2014.`

I search a way with SimpleDateFormat. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `E Day name in week` and `M Month in year`?

Comment: Propbaly you should strip out the ordinals with a regular expression before using DateFormat.parse().

Comment: That's what I have done. I wanted just to know if there's a way with SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: @user230137 Mind if you say that in the question? Aside from that comment, the question really reads like you're trying to get us to show you how to parse the dates *period*. Judging from that comment, you already know of one way, but are wondering whether it's possible to do it using a different approach. A title like "Is it possible to parse these dates using SimpleDateFormat" with description something along the lines of "I have these dates, and am currently using <approach> to parse them. Is there a different way with SimpleDateFormat" is much more likely to be better received.

Comment: My question would be : is there a mask to parse theses dates using SimpleDateFormat?. English is not my native language so at the moment I couldn't exprime my question like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simpleDateformat, try the mask:

```
"E, dd MMMMM yyyy"
```

eg: Sunday 09 February 2014

there is no way within simpleDateformat to add the th, rd etc... you would have to do this manually:

```
// http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.*;

String getDayOfMonthSuffix(final int n) {
    checkArgument(n >= 1 && n <= 31, "illegal day of month: " + n);
if (n >= 11 && n <= 13) {
    return "th";
}
switch (n % 10) {
    case 1:  return "st";
    case 2:  return "nd";
    case 3:  return "rd";
    default: return "th";
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

This code just uses a regex with a lookbehind to replace all occurrences of `nd|rd|th|st` before parsing the string using the pattern `EEE MMM dd, yyyy`.

```
String value = "Sunday February 09th, 2014";
String formatted = value.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)(nd|rd|th|st)", "");
System.out.println(formatted);

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd, yyyy");     
Date date = format.parse(formatted);
```

Comment: @user230137 Sorry for posting the solution you have already used, but in my defense I can't really predict that and your question doesn't include that.  Also from the accepted answer you have chosen you don't appear to be `parsing` but `formatting`.

Comment: No I wanted to parse. I have accepted the other answer because from the answer I figured out that there isn't a mask for such date

Answer (score 0):

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM dd yyyy");
String dateInString = "Fri, June 7 2013";       
    try {
       Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
       System.out.println(date);
   System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Try something like this. Ref: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/

Comment: What is about the numerals that the OP asked for ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleTimeZone pdt = new SimpleTimeZone(-8 * 60 * 60 * 1000, "PST");
pdt.setStartRule(DateFields.APRIL, 1, DateFields.SUNDAY, 2*60*60*1000);
pdt.setEndRule(DateFields.OCTOBER, -1, DateFields.SUNDAY, 2*60*60*1000);
// Format the current time.
SimpleDateFormat formatter
 = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy.mm.dd e 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");
Date currentTime_1 = new Date();
String dateString = formatter.format(currentTime_1);
// Parse the previous string back into a Date.
ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
Date currentTime_2 = formatter.parse(dateString, pos);
```

Refer this for more knowledge;
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I have got error with DateFields. What should I import?